# Call web URL with PHP script from a shell script on Mac OS-X

Tags: php, macos, shell

I have a server with a PHP script that pulls data from a source and populates a database. I need to call this PHP script repeatedly, each time with a different parameter.

I need to create a shell script on a Mac (which reads in a text file with the list of parameters - that part is not a problem) and for each parameter, runs the PHP script/URL in a web browser.

The PHP is on a remote server, so I need to load a web browser instance (safari or firefox) and instruct it to load the URL (ie. something like http:/myserver.com/scriptname.php?param1). Then I need to wait for it to complete and trigger the same URL with the next parameter.

I don't know the incantation to launch the web browser with a URL (I am a former Windows dev not a Mac OS-X pro, yet). I also don't think there is a way to detect when the script completes - but I don't want to end up with 100 instances of the browser running simultaneously.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be done in a web browser rather than with something like cURL or wget?

Comment: curl / wget seem more proper candidates indeed, although, as I see it, a local cronjob on said server could even be more effective....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need it to hit a php page on a remote server, don't use a browser. Use curl, or some equivalent.

`curl http:/myserver.com/scriptname.php?param1`

Comment: Excellent - I didn't know you could do that! Works perfectly, exactly what I needed. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

`open -a Safari http://stackoverflow.com`